# Dictionary in python dict

Tags: python, dynamic, dictionary

**Question**

i want to dynamically create a dictionary with dynamic keys and value's

In this dictionary i need to put another dict like so

**Example**

---

```
{"Key Name of file" : "Value Name",
 "Specs" : [{"spec1" : "round", "spec2" : "large", "spec3": "pink"}]}
```

---

How can i achieve this?

Following code does not work

```
save = {}
save['Key name of file'] = 'Value Name'
save['specs'] = []
save['specs'].append([{'spec1', 'spec2', 'spec3'}])
save['specs'][0] = 'round'
save['specs']['spec2'] = 'large'
```

Comment: dictionay have a pair of key and value, you doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
save['specs'].append([{'spec1', 'spec2', 'spec3'}])
```

You're appending a 1-element list containing a 3-element set, `[{'spec1', 'spec2', 'spec3'}]`, rather than the 3-element set itself. So, `save['specs'][0]` is not a 1-element list, which is not what you wanted. So:

```
save['specs'].append({'spec1', 'spec2', 'spec3'})
```

---

Your second problem is in the same line: `{a, b, c}` is a set, not a dict; a dict has to have keys *and values*. So, maybe:

```
save['specs'].append({'spec1': None, 'spec2': None, 'spec3': None})
```

Or, maybe just leave the keys and values out because you're going to set them later anyway:

```
save['specs'].append({})
```

---

Next:

```
save['specs'][0] = 'round'
```

This just replaces whatever you appended to `save['specs']` with the string `'round'`, which defeats all the hard work you've just done. You probably wanted this:

```
save['specs'][0]['spec1'] = 'round'
```

So, instead of replacing the whole dict, you're just setting its `'spec1'` value.

---

Next:

```
save['specs']['spec2'] = 'large'
```

`save['specs']` is a list, not a dict. You can't look up the `'spec2'`th element in a list. You wanted the `'spec2'` key in the 0th element in the list:

```
save['specs'][0]['spec2'] = 'large'
```

---

And finally, you never set the value for `'spec3'` to `'pink'`. Obviously you have to do that. Hopefully from the previous two lines you can see how to do so.